# Yii2 DetailView Alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment, yii2

I am using Yii2's `DetailView` widget and I want it to be center aligned. I have tried `'options' => ['align' => 'center']` but it's not giving me the expected output. The output looks like this:

[image]

It ridiculously looks awful. Is their any other way to center `DetailView`?

Here's the original output without the `'options' => ['align' => 'center']`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to set your options as follows:

```
'options'=>['class'=>'text-center']
```

Which makes use of the bootstrap-class which is generally used to center texts. Now your text-centering will be overridden by other default table-styles. In this case you could simply add those lines to your css which will absolutely do the trick:

```
.detail-view.text-center > tbody > tr > th,
.detail-view.text-center > tbody > tr > td {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Voilà. Now both your columns should be centered. The explicit path declaration with the `>`-sign is to ensure data nested further within your detail-view will be left as is and not centered.